# Relationship between Contiguity and Absolute Continuity

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Suppose $Q \ll P$ for $Q, P$ probability measures on some measurable space $\Omega, \mathcal{F}$.

Define $P^n(A) \equiv [P(A)]^n \quad \forall A \in \mathcal{F}$, and similarly for $Q^n$.

I wish to show that $P^n \triangleleft Q^n \iff P=Q$

Obviously $P= Q$ implies the contiguity trivially, so I essentially just want to show the forward implication, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

1. Fixing $A \in \mathcal{F}$, we trivially have $Q(A) = 0$ whenever $P(A) = 0$ by $Q \ll P$
2. If $P(A) = 1$, then $P^n(A) \rightarrow 1$.  Thus $Q(A) = 1$, for if not, then $Q^n(A) \rightarrow 0 \implies P^n(A) \rightarrow 0$ by contiguity $\implies$ contradiction.

Thus it suffices to show equality on all $A$ such that $0< P(A) < 1$, but I have no idea how to approach it in this scenario because none of my assumptions really help me.  Any hints would be greatly appreciated.